# Tilde Notation in Additive Combinatorics

Tags: number-theory, notation, additive-combinatorics

A, B are some finite subsets of a abelian group.

|A + B| ~ |A|

The problem is I couldn't precisely understand what does ~ mean in that case.

For example, it could be found in notes of [Tao's lectures on Additive Combinatorics](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/254a.1.03w/notes1.dvi)

Page 8, he is defining essentialy B-invariant set.

It is obvious that ~ means that A+B is not much larger than A but I need the precise definition. For me it's a bit too bad using ~ for something else than equivalence relation.

Thanks!